# file ended while scanning use of \xdblarg

Tags: errors

In the compilation of my LaTeX document I get this error in the very beginning (1st line) and the error is `file ended while scanning use of \xdblarg`. The following is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4,2side]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing                                       
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{arial}\usepackage{authblk}          % for affiliation
\usepackage{graphicx}         % for pictures
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}                  % for maths mode
\usepackage{siunitx}          % This helps to write units such as angstrom, micrometer, etc.
\usepackage{nicefrac}  % for nice fraction
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{mhchem}           % for molecular formulae as in chemistry.
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}                       % for bold font caption
\usepackage{enumitem}         % package for creating lists
\usepackage{color}            % for using colour
\usepackage{hyperref}         % for labeling and cross-referencing in texts which is 
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage[square, super]{natbib}         % for the bibliography\reference citation number as a supescript in square brackets.  
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}             % This helps to include the References(Bibliography) in the table of contents if it isn't 
                                             % already included there.                                     
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}            % This helps to include the Appendices in 

\begin{document}
```

So the error points to line#1 only. Can someone help me get rid of this problem please?
Thanks

Comment: I get no error (apart from the missing `arial.sty` that's not on my system). The options should be `a4paper` and `twoside` rather than `a4` and `2side`, but these just issue a warning.

Answer (score 17):

I have found that this will cause the "File ended wile scanning use of @xdblarg" error:

\subsubsection{This is the title of the numbered subsubsection]

Note the square bracket on the right end, which should be a curly bracket.  I think that any command that is terminated with the wrong bracket could cause this error.

I found it by putting "\end{document}" in each page until I located the page that caused the error, and focusing on that page.

Comment: Was that line 1 of some included file? The full error message should have shown both the line number of the file plus the content of that line.

Comment: In my case, that was the only error, and there was no line number.  Nothing in the line content was quoted.  There was nothing to indicate where the error came from or what caused it, unless you knew what "@xdblarg" is; apparently xdblarg is an internal LaTex command that is invoked during execution of the command option interpreter or the subsection command.  That's why I needed to use temporary "\end{document}" lines to "scroll" through the document to find it.